# How do I create new content pages for my Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, content, single

I am using [Underscores](http://underscores.me/) starter theme and I've created a custom post type `video`.

```
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Video', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Videos', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', ),
    'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-video-alt2',
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'post',
);
register_post_type( 'video', $args );
```

I am able to display the latest posts from `video` on the homepage (which is a custom page template) but when I visit the video link, I get `Oops! That page can’t be found!`

I've created a new file `single-video.php` and inside I'm getting the video template

```
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'video' );
```

I've also created another file `content-video.php` which lives inside `template-parts` folder and is the copy of the original `content.php` file

But it's not working, I'm still getting `Page Not Found` when I visit the video url.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your dashboard go to settings/permalinks.  Hit save.  You should be able to see your cpts now.

Comment: Thank you that solved it. Do I need the `single-video.php` though? Because if I remove it, the page still loads fine.

Comment: It's not exactly necessary to have a `single-video.php` template unless you want to change the code for that post type. If it's not specified, it'll default to the `single.php` template file in the theme. Check out the WordPress template hierarchy for more info https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: @ian beat me to it

Comment: So I need it if I want to create a different style from the one on `single.php`

Comment: to be clear.  if you want ALL single posts of every type to be different than no, just change the single.php.  If you want videos to have a different appearance of their own when viewed then make changes to single-video.php

Comment: No, not different style, but different code structure. Lets say you don't want your video post type to have a sidebar, but the `single.php` template uses a sidebar. So you don't end up affecting all other regular posts, you could create a `single-video.php` template without a sidebar and be good. For styles, you can for the most part target a post type specifically if you need to adjust styles there, regardless of the template being used.

Answer (score 2):

you should create `content-video.php` inside `template-parts` folder.

And try resetting permalinks. That means:

Go to Settings > Permalinks

Change Permalink setting to plain and save

Change permalink settings to your desired one again and save

It should fix the issue.

Comment: no need to make any changes on the permalinks page.  Just hitting save is enough

Comment: May be. I usually solve the way I've described.

Comment: your way works...just extra steps

Comment: You don't even have to hit save, just visiting the permalinks page flushes the rules.