# Remove single page for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, single

I have a custom theme with a bunch of custom post types. I want to keep my "news" post type to display as a paginated list (that links directly to the external news article - already figured this part out), but I want to get rid of all single pages that get created when I add a news news post. Basically the opposite of this: [How do I create new content pages for my Custom Post Type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/262712/how-do-i-create-new-content-pages-for-my-custom-post-type). I apologize if this as too vague, not a developer. Just let me know what additional info is needed to determine a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are linking to external news articles you would like to prevent users from getting to the `/news-article/article-title/` url that is created for a new post and would have no real content?

You could do something like this: [How to disable the single view for a custom post type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128636/how-to-disable-the-single-view-for-a-custom-post-type)

The code below is from that answer. Add it to your functions.php, making sure to change `news_article` to the actual post type slug. This should 301 redirect a user trying to hit that single post. You may want to test this first using 302 as many browsers will cache a 301 and can be difficult to clear out.

It [defaults](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) to 302, so remove the `, 301` to set it to default if you'd like to try with a 302.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'news_article_redirect' );

function news_article_redirect() {
  $queried_post_type = get_query_var('news_article');
  if ( is_single() && 'news_article' ==  $queried_post_type ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url(), 301 );
    exit;
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly. I saw that solution as I was searching for an answer. So, the page still gets created, I am just redirecting any link to it, correct?

Comment: Yep, the page will still get "created". WordPress will generate a post object that contains all the standard data for a post (id, slug, title, etc) when you add a news article. With the way template hierarchy works, no matter how many template files you try to remove to sort of cheat your way into not generating a page with markup, you'll always end up back at index.php being used to spit out _something_. So the best way to avoid a user hitting content that technically exists, is to redirect it somewhere. Your users won't accidentally hit those posts if you never link to them form anywhere.

Comment: You might prefer to redirect to your news article list. To do that use `wp_redirect( get_post_type_archive_link( 'news_article' ), 301 );`